# How to find corresponding cells in row based on lookup?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 5 rows with 10 columns. Below this 5x10 grid, I populate a cell with a value that is listed in column 1 of the grid. "ABC" for example.

If "ABC" is row 3, column 1, I want to them get the values in row 3, columns 4, 5, 6. Those three values will go into cells just above or below the "ABC" cell that is below the grid.

The value where "ABC" is will change, as I get info from different rows, but will always correspond to a value in column 1 of the 5x10 grid. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: There are other, simpler ways to do that. Is `LOOKUP` a must?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-ywtRBPqWaPnYnVFfe3QXJCD0OZFCVLR8fobN1misB0/edit#gid=0) 
A10 is your "ABC" cell 
and below find the formula that returns Values from columns 4,5,6 (or any other - just add)

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({Sheet1!$A1:$J6},
"select Col4, Col5, Col6 
where Col1 ='"&A10&"'",0),"no data")
```

Comment: Perfect! By the way, did you share that sheet anonymously? I don't see any identifying info on it. If so, can you say how?

Comment: @4thSpace I just get shareable link, so anyone on the internet can see it. you can find info on Share\Advanced

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way

```
=if(A8=A4,{D4,E4,F4})
```

[image]

No need to over complicate things

Comment: Of course, not flexible.

Comment: Your question is _"... I want to them get the values in row 3, columns 4, 5, 6."_ Those values are not flexible